# Thread safe progress indicator in scala

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, progress-bar

in scala imagine you have a long list and you map a function that makes an independent operation on each element:

```
val myList = List(....)
def fct(...) = {...}

myList.map(elem => fct(elem))
```

since `fct` uses only `val` and unmutable operations, it can be easily parallelized as such

```
myList.par.map(elem => fct(elem))
```

With a `for`:

```
for(elem <- myList) {
    fct(elem)
}
```

My question is how to have a sort of **progress bar** inside the command that shows at what level we are in the list.
I thought of something like:

```
var i = o
```

before the loop and inside

```
i += 1
print(i + (" "*100) + "\r")
```

but this will ruin the possibility of parallelization.

Comment: "Ruin" how? You'll have to synchronize the progress counter, so yeah, it will be slower than without the progress notification, but it's still doable.

Comment: yes maybe with a volatile `var @volatile i: Int = 0`

Comment: @volatile does not help here, because incrementing an integer is not an atomic operation, it getting the integer, adding 1 to it and setting it again. Aaron gave you a working and safe answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use an atomic integer or long, depending on the size of the collection, to make things thread-safe:

```
def trackProgress[T](fn:T => Unit, xs: collection.parallel.ParSeq[T]) {
  val total = xs.length
  val done = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger()
  xs.foreach { x =>
    fn(x)
    val curDone = done.incrementAndGet()
    println("%s%% done".format(curDone.floatValue / total * 100))
  }
}

trackProgress(fct, myList.par)
```